# Lubuntu 18.04 Bionic: Tor browser installation - SIGNATURE VERIFICATION FAILED

Tags: 18.04, apt, lubuntu, gnupg, tor

I was trying to install Tor browser using apt (sudo apt install torbrowser-launcher), but I got "SIGNATURE VERIFICATION FAILED" error. None of the following solutions that I had found online worked for me:

`gpg --homedir "$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir/" --refresh-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com`

`gpg --homedir "$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir/" --refresh-keys --keyserver pgp.mit.edu`

`gpg --homedir "$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir/" --refresh-keys --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net`

`gpg --homedir "$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir/" --refresh-keys --keyserver keys.openpgp.org`

`gpg --homedir "$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir/" --refresh-keys --keyserver keyring.debian.org`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION: What worked though was:**

`gpg --homedir "$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir/" --refresh-keys --keyserver zimmermann.mayfirst.org`

I found the address of that specific keyserver on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_server_(cryptographic)

Hope it'll be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION THAT WORKED for me :
thanks to previous comment I could list servers (from wikipedia article) and chose openpgp :

```
gpg --homedir "$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir/" --refresh-keys --keyserver keys.openpgp.org
```